# ListView inside ViewPager problems small Display

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I'm implementing a listView inside a Fragment, that is attached to ViewPager. In the fragment I have to display also a button that would add new elements to the listView (managed by an Adapter).

On big screens (4'' or more) the lisView is displayed good, but on smaller screen (less than 4'') users see only one element, and they would have to scroll a microscopic listView.

I wish to command to the listView to show at least 3 elements before becoming scrollable, and instead allow the user to scroll the fragment and to make everything above the listView disappear including the button

[image: The problem, the listView has just space for one element]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_custom_timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_timer_black_24dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:text="@string/add_custom_timer" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    tools:context=".fragments.ActiveTimersFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_active_timers_emptyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_active_timers" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_active_timers_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/col"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="8dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
android:minHeight="100dp"
```

to the ListView element in your xml.
play with the 100 value, until you get the 3 lines visible.

**Update:**

You'd also need to put the entire layout in a ScrollView to make to whole thing scrollable, and make its height wrap_content instead of match_parent:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_custom_timer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_timer_black_24dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:text="@string/add_custom_timer" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    tools:context=".fragments.ActiveTimersFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_active_timers_emptyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_active_timers" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_active_timers_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="100dp" />
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried with several dimensions but it doesn't work :( Any other advice?